# mysql select between MAX -n1 AND MAX-n2

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I need to select data between 2 values from a table by using MAX because each SID has different VID and i need to get some data just like below.

i need to get these VIDs from SIDs :

```
SID 1: "5, 6, 7, 8"<br/>
SID 2: "2, 3, 4, 5"<br/>
SID 3: ""<br/>
SID 4: "3, 4, 5, 6"<br/>
```

My code:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `tests` WHERE `VID` BETWEEN MAX(`VID`)-7 AND MAX(`VID`)-4 ORDER BY `SID` ASC, `VID` ASC");
```

My table:

```
INSERT INTO `tests` (`ID`, `SID`, `VID`, `Text`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'test'),
(2, 1, 2, 'test'),
(3, 1, 3, 'test'),
(4, 1, 4, 'test'),
(5, 1, 5, 'test'),
(6, 1, 6, 'test'),
(7, 1, 7, 'test'),
(8, 1, 8, 'test'),
(9, 1, 9, 'test'),
(10, 1, 10, 'test'),
(11, 1, 11, 'test'),
(12, 2, 1, 'test'),
(13, 2, 2, 'test'),
(14, 2, 3, 'test'),
(15, 2, 4, 'test'),
(16, 2, 5, 'test'),
(17, 2, 6, 'test'),
(18, 2, 7, 'test'),
(19, 2, 8, 'test'),
(20, 3, 1, 'test'),
(21, 3, 2, 'test'),
(22, 3, 3, 'test'),
(23, 4, 1, 'test'),
(24, 4, 2, 'test'),
(25, 4, 3, 'test'),
(26, 4, 4, 'test'),
(27, 4, 5, 'test'),
(28, 4, 6, 'test'),
(29, 4, 7, 'test'),
(30, 4, 8, 'test'),
(31, 4, 9, 'test');
```

Thanks ♥ :)

Comment: use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`

Comment: What @MarianNasry said. WHERE cannot be used with aggregate functions whole HAVING can.

Comment: i tried HAVING but it returns nothing, i think something is wrong with MAX(`VID`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it, that's what i needed

```
SELECT MAX(vid)-n1 AS max1, MAX(vid)-n2 AS max2 FROM `tests` GROUP BY sid
```

thanks to all :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best way but this works:

```
SET @min = (SELECT MAX(vid) FROM tests)-7;
SET @max = (SELECT MAX(vid) FROM tests)-4;
SELECT * FROM tests WHERE vid BETWEEN @min AND @max ORDER BY sid ASC, vid ASC;
```

or a 1-liner:

```
SELECT * FROM tests WHERE vid BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(vid) FROM tests)-7 AND (SELECT MAX(vid) FROM tests)-4 ORDER BY sid ASC, vid ASC
```

Comment: thanks, i tried that before
but this only returns VIDs of the SID 1 because it has the max VID between the other SIDs

Comment: I get 12 rows using this select statement and your table: https://imgur.com/SJAv6Sg

Comment: i appreciate that it works for the test table but i don't know why it doesn't work on my main table, it has more than 6000 rows